# Install a new OS from raspberry command line interface

Tags: command-line, raspberry-pi

How can I install a new OS from the raspberry command line if I have the OS in my SD memory card ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only easily install a new OS from a running machine, if you have a NOOBS SD Card. (it's possible, but given your question, I don't think you want to be going down that road... no offence!)

When booting, hold shift on the keyboard to get back into the NOOBS menu, and you can pick an OS to install again.

Alternatively, you can remove the SD card from the Pi, put it into another machine, download and write a new *.img to the card to install a new OS.

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding, your answers is good. Thank you

Comment: No worries :) if you felt the answer was useful, please give it an upvote as well ;)